# Why doesn't TypeScript complain if I try to import a non-existent default export?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I have some code that I'm converting from not-TypeScript CommonJS files to TypeScript ES6 modules, and I ran into some issues where I needed to import using `import * as x` instead of `import x`:

The original code was something like this:

```js
const luxon = require('luxon');

console.log(luxon.DateTime.now().toString());
```

And then I mistakenly changed it to:

```js
import luxon from 'luxon';

console.log(luxon.DateTime.now().toString());
```

... which leads to the error:

> Cannot read property 'DateTime' of undefined

The problem is that luxon has no default export, and `import luxon from 'luxon'` turns into code like `const luxon = require('luxon').default;`.

So the correct import is:

```
import * as luxon from 'luxon'; // or even better, import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
```

My question is, why doesn't TypeScript complain that I'm using a non-existent default export, and is there anything I can do to make it detect this for me?

I've found that it *does* complain if I try to use a non-existent default export from a TypeScript module, but not from JavaScript (even if I've installed the types for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `luxon` npm package doesn't include the typings, so you need to also install `@types/luxon` as a dev dependency.

If you already installed the types and typescript doesn't complain about the import that it has no default export, it means you have enabled `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` in tsconfig which doesn't work for es modules.

This is how typescript tries to import it:
[image]

but luxon does have `__esModule` set to `true`.
[image]

Depending on your other dependencies, I would disable `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` and typescript will generate the proper error:

`error TS1192: Module '".../@types/luxon/index"' has no default export.`